# How to print each piece of information scraped on a new line

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi the code is working fine but i was wondering if there was a way that i could make it print the scraped information after a certain point on a new line. For this code i would like each company's information to print on a new line. Also the site the code is set up to scrape is listed below. Thanks so much for your help and reading.
https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class WebScrape {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("running...");
        Document document;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active").get();
            Elements body = document.select("div#scr-res-table tbody");

            String title = document.title(); 
            print("  Title: " + title); 
            for(Element p : body) {
                  System.out.println(p.text());

             }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        print("done");
    }

    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: It would help if you post an example of the text that you want to split.

Comment: GE General Electric Company 5.79 -0.21 -3.50% 234.597M 108.097M 50.646B N/A             
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                                                                                                             
   BAC Bank of America Corporation 20.87 -1.00 -4.57% 110.266M 91.593M 181.06B 8.48   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::         like those would be the first two lines printed in seperate lines instead of like one mass of text and i just used the ":" to break up the lines

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are getting the entire table body as one element. You can fix this by doing:

```
  Elements body = document.select("div#scr-res-table tbody tr");
```

And then the following code should print each table row on a separate line

```
  for(Element p : body) {
    System.out.println(p.text());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a prototype based on your code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    print("running...");
    Document document;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active").get();
        Elements body = document.select("div#scr-res-table tbody");

        String title = document.title();
        print("  Title: " + title);
        String table = printTable(body.first()); //<---remember to select the first found of the table body.
        print(table);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    print("done");
}

public static void print(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
/**
 * Extract data fields from each row <tr>....</tr>
 */
public static String printLine(Element row) {
    //Each <td> cell has different content, you need to look at the 
    //html source and extract them individually, here I extract 3 of them as example

    String symbol = row.select("td[aria-label='Symbol'] a").first().text();
    String name = row.select("td[aria-label='Name']").first().text();
    String volume = row.select("td[aria-label='Volume'] span").first().text();
    return symbol + " " + name + " " + volume;
}

/**
 * Take in a <tbody> tree, and print the every row inside as a string.
 */
public static String printTable(Element tableBody){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Elements allRows = tableBody.select("tbody").first().children();
    for(Element row : allRows){
        String rowString = printLine(row);
        sb.append(rowString).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

basically you need to extract each row from the table. See `printTable`

For each row, you need to extract each text content. See `printLine`

The example output is

```
Hello world.
running...
Title: Most Active Stocks Today - Yahoo Finance
GE General Electric Company 234.597M
BAC Bank of America Corporation 110.266M
F Ford Motor Company 97.974M
....
done
```

You need to add in your own formatting later.

Comment: Thanks so much for that helps a lot. I'm newer to coding so thanks for the support.

Comment: does it answer your question?